# Visual Studio Code - How to do code navigation extention for custom module loader

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, monaco-editor

We have an inhouse module loader at work and I'm trying to do an extention for vscode that add code navigation. The module loader work in a way similar to requirejs but is closer normal `require()`.

It replace `require()` with a global `include()` function.

and `module.exports` with a `exportModules()` function.

Then use acorn.js to build an AST and parse that to get the location of everything. There more to it but I don't think the rest is relevent to this question.

I did some research and found this extention that does something like what I want to do but maybe simpler, since it doesn't provide function to function goto.

https://github.com/anacierdem/vscode-requirejs

I'm wondering if there's a simpler way than finding everything by hand throught regex or in my case walking the AST tree that the module loader provide me with.

The problem seem simple, tell vs code that an `include()` is actually a `require` and give it the uri to that file so it can complete path and give proper code navigation. But it doesn't seem like it's that easy to do at all.

What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is a [TypeScript Server plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Writing-a-Language-Service-Plugin). These plugins can augment or change the TypeScript language server's behavior (the TS server powers both vscode's js and ts intellisense). Plugins can be [contributed by extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.typescriptServerPlugins)

What I do not know is how easy it would be for a plugin to add support for a new way or importing and exporting in a module. Depending on how much support you need, I suspect it will be very involved